# sort text file based on logic

Tags: sort

I have .txt file which has 1000 character string per line and the file has millions of rows.
Client's new requirement is to sort this file based on below logic. Thanks in advance, I am new to unix and could not find solution on the forum.

If character position 6 thru 11 is 'CIP002' then sort based on character position 13 thru 21
if character position 6 thru 11 is 'CIP003' sort based on characters in position 20 thru 28)

**BEFORE SORT**

```
00001CIP002_123456789ABCDEFJ
00002CIP002_123456790EFGHIJK
87654CIP003_ABCDEFJ123456789
87655CIP003_EFGHIJK123456790
```

**AFTER SORT**

```
00001CIP002_123456789ABCDEFJ
87654CIP003_ABCDEFJ123456789
00002CIP002_123456790EFGHIJK
87655CIP003_EFGHIJK123456790
```

Comment: What about lines where 6 to 11 is neither of those? Also, how do you decide the order  in case of tie? Unchanged from the input? lexical order on the full line? CIP002 before CIP003?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward.
Use python / awk / perl / bash / whatever to code up the CIP{2,3} business logic,
and put together a pipeline.

You want an output stream that looks like this:

```
$ cat two_column.txt
123456789 00001CIP002_123456789ABCDEFJ
123456790 00002CIP002_123456790EFGHIJK
123456789 87654CIP003_ABCDEFJ123456789
123456790 87655CIP003_EFGHIJK123456790
```

Now sort in the usual way, and strip that prefix in a post-processing step.

```
$ cat two_column.txt | sort | awk '{print $2}'  > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue ;)

```
gawk '$1 ~ /.{5}CIP002_.*/ {print substr($0, 13, 9)" "$0}
$1 ~ /.{5}CIP003_.*/ {print substr($0, 20, 9)" "$0}' before.txt | sort | awk '{print $2}'
```

It should work with `gawk`

Explanations:

- `gawk '$1 ~ /.{5}CIP002_.*/ {print substr($0, 13, 9)" "$0} $1 ~ /.{5}CIP003_.*/ {print substr($0, 20, 9)" "$0}' yourfile.txt`

  - `$1 ~ /.{5}CIP002_.*/` filters line with `CIP002` :

    - `.{5}` matches with the five first chars
    - followed by `CIP002_`
    - followed by any string
  - `print substr($0, 13, 9)" "$0` is to print into the first column the sorting part of the data:

    - `substr($0, 13, 9)` cuts the line from char 13 to 21
    - the instruction prints the `123456789` as the first column, then a space, then the data

Output sample:

```
123456789 00001CIP002_123456789ABCDEFJ
123456790 00002CIP002_123456790EFGHIJK
123456789 87654CIP003_ABCDEFJ123456789
123456790 87655CIP003_EFGHIJK123456790
```

- `| sort` : a pipe that redirects the generated output into the `sort` command which only sorts it according to the first column.

Output sample:

```
123456789 00001CIP002_123456789ABCDEFJ
123456789 87654CIP003_ABCDEFJ123456789
123456790 00002CIP002_123456790EFGHIJK
123456790 87655CIP003_EFGHIJK123456790
```

- `| awk {print $2}` : only prints the data, without the sorting column

Output sample:

```
00001CIP002_123456789ABCDEFJ
87654CIP003_ABCDEFJ123456789
00002CIP002_123456790EFGHIJK
87655CIP003_EFGHIJK123456790
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches could be:

Prepend the sort key and remove after sorting:

```
<your-file awk '{
  print substr($0,6,6) == "CIP002" ? substr($0,13,9) : substr($0,20,9), $0}' |
    sort -k1,1 |
    cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Or insert a marker before the sort key:

```
<your-file perl -pe '
  substr($_, substr($_,5,6) eq "CIP002" ? 12 : 19, 0) = "|"' |
  sort -t '|' -k2,2.9 |
  tr -d '|'
```

(assuming `|` doesn't occur otherwise in the input).

Ties are resolved by `sort`'s last resort comparison which compares the whole lines lexically.